# Assign all methods and properties of prototype B into prototype A?

Tags: javascript, typescript, prototype, mixins

I have a class A that is a subset of class B. It shares many of the properties and methods of class B.

Class A lacks implementation though. So I want all all functionality in class B to to go into class A.

```
ClassA.prototype = ClassB.prototype;
```

or

```
ClassA.prototype += ClassB.prototype
```

But it seems I have to:

```
ClassA.prototype.methodA = ClassB.prototype.methodA
ClassA.prototype.methodB = ClassB.prototype.methodB
ClassA.prototype.methodC = ClassB.prototype.methodC
ClassA.prototype.methodD = ClassB.prototype.methodD
```

for every single method and property. Is there no way I can put implementations in B into A at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true you can't overwrite the `prototype` property of functions created via `class` syntax, because it's both read-only and non-configurable. You can do it if you use `function` syntax instead as [Fullstack Guy points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57754781/157247).

But you probably want to make `ClassA` *extend* `ClassB`:

```
class ClassA extends ClassB {
    // ...
}
```

Live Example:

```js
class ClassB {
    methodA() {
        console.log("methodA");
    }
    methodB() {
        console.log("methodB");
    }
    methodC() {
        console.log("methodC");
    }
    methodD() {
        console.log("methodD");
    }
}
class ClassA extends ClassB {
    // ...
}
new ClassA().methodA();
```

If not, though, you can copy all the methods using a loop:

```
for (const name of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(ClassB.prototype)) {
    const method = ClassB.prototype[name];
    if (typeof method === "function") {
        ClassA.prototype[name] = ClassB.prototype[name];
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
class ClassB {
    methodA() {
        console.log("methodA");
    }
    methodB() {
        console.log("methodB");
    }
    methodC() {
        console.log("methodC");
    }
    methodD() {
        console.log("methodD");
    }
}
class ClassA {
    // ...
}
for (const name of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(ClassB.prototype)) {
    const method = ClassB.prototype[name];
    if (typeof method === "function") {
        ClassA.prototype[name] = ClassB.prototype[name];
    }
}
new ClassA().methodA();
```

But note that if `ClassB` is a subclass, `super` within the methods will continue to access `ClassB`'s superclass methods, it won't either be invalid or access `ClassA`'s superclass methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.create` to make a prototype of `ClassA` inherit from the `prototyoe` of `ClassB`:

```js
function ClassB(){
}
ClassB.prototype.methodA = function(){
   console.log("methodA");
}

 
function ClassA(){
  //no implementation
}
//Make the prototype of Class A inherit from the ptottype of Class B
ClassA.prototype = Object.create(ClassB.prototype);
const classA =  new ClassA();
classA.methodA();
```

The above is for function constructors, if you want to use ES6 classes, then you simply need to `extend` the `ClassB`:

```js
class ClassB{
  methodA(){ console.log("methodA"); }
}
class ClassA extends ClassB{
}

const classA = new ClassA();
classA.methodA();


// When you extend another class, the instance methods of super class are inherited
// in the prototype property of the child class
ClassA.prototype.methodA();
```

As @T.J. Crowder rightfully said the `prototype` property of the `class` Object is not configurable and as result you cannot assign another object to it. Also you cannot change the `configurable` to `true` once it has been set to `false`. The only option is to copy the member functions in a loop.

You can verify this through the `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()` method:

```js
class ClassA{
}

//configurable and writable is false
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(ClassA, "prototype"));
```

Comment: The OP must be using `class` syntax. Otherwise, their first example would have mostly worked. This won't work with `class` syntax.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder let me add that as well